# iOS: NSURLSession is not working everytime when launched in background (with silent push nofitication)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, background-process, nsurlsession

If I call the NSURLSession when the app is in the background with push notification, the response is received may be only one time a three.

```
 NSLog(@"SEND: LAUNCH FUNCTION!!!!");
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response
if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"SEND: RESPONSE FUNCTION GOOD!!!!");
        NSMutableArray* responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self parseAndAddLovAll:responseArray toArray:self.objects];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"SEND: RESPONSE FUNCTION BAD!!!!");
    }
            }] resume];
```

(If I call the NSURLSession when the app is active, no problem, it works every time).

EDIT:

We can see in that video that when I push the **1ST** time, it launches the NSURLSession, without answer. If I click a **2ND** time, the answer of the **1ST** appears, followed by the answer of the **2ND** one.

```
*SEND: LAUNCH FUNCTION!!!!* =>** launch the NSURLSession.  
*SEND: RESPONSE FUNCTION GOOD!!!!*** => Response ok from the NSURLSession.  
*SEND: RESPONSE FUNCTION BAD!!!!*** => Response not ok from the NSURLSession.  
*SEND: FINISHED!!!!*** => Download execution finished with success.
```

I put a demo in a video:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyGKhjOLOSE)

EDIT:

```
Call of the function:  
      dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
      dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
                  ListOfValueSync * lovSync = [[ListOfValueSync alloc] init];

            // Synchronization
            BOOL ret = [lovSync getAllListOfValueAll];
            });
```

What could cause that problem?

Comment: Where do you call the function to be executed in Background?

Comment: Your app is already in background when you get the notification, and then you are calling another function in background thread.Try this one, 

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) { NSMutableArray* responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
  [self parseAndAddLovAll:responseArray toArray:self.objects];
        }] resume];

Comment: @ManishKumar I have to put it, or I will have that error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681470/ios-error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-132001-save-on-the-context-aborted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your call of the function.
You cannot use your download queue in this case.

Instead of this, please use dispatch_main

Answer (score 1):

To initiate Download when App is in Background as per [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> To support this background mode, enable the Remote notifications
>   option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in
>   your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the
>   **UIBackgroundModes** key with the remote-notification value in your app’s
>   Info.plist file.)
>
> For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the
>   notification’s payload must include the **content-available** key with its
>   value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in
>   the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app
>   delegate’s
>   **`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`**
>   method. Your implementation of that method should download the
>   relevant content and integrate it into your app.

To remember while using **Background Execution**

> Do minimal work while running in the background. The execution time
>   given to background apps is more constrained than the amount of time
>   given to the foreground app. Apps that spend too much time executing
>   in the background can be throttled back by the system or terminated.

Comment: @ iphonic All you written is right, but I have already done all that. What is strange, is that the push notification works every time, it launches the code, no problem on that part, what is problematic, is when it calls the NSURLSession that sometimes works, and sometimes not. Sometimes I get a response, and sometimes not.

Comment: Are you sending a silent Push?

Comment: @ΩlostA May be you can Log and check whether Push is triggering the function or, not?

Comment: Yes, it is a silent Push, I put the content-available to 1, with no badge, no alert, but it is still the same. The function is triggered every time with no problem. But when it arrives to the NSURLSession, it launches it, but the response is received not everytime. Some times, if I send one push, there is no response of the NSURLSession, but if I launches another push, there is two response (the new one, and the previous one) that come.

Comment: @ΩlostA See my edit, may be your api service is taking more time to fetch data, and due to that the system might be termination the service.

Comment: a iphonic it is instantaneous, i don't think that it is the problem. It is like the wifi of the ipad is not working, and suddenly unblocks. What I don't understand is why when I click on one push, there is no answer to the NSURLSession. I click a second time, there is no answer to the NSURLSession. I click a third time, there is the 3 answers consecutively at the same time... very strange

Comment: @ΩlostA I have seen everything is fine, I suspect the api service only, can you put the Network Service on a button call and see if it is working perfectly, on multiple calls like it is happening in the case of Push.

Comment: @ iphonic I tried to do the push notification with that : https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/aerogear-unifiedpush-rest/index.html  it is the same problem. I need to push two or three notifications to have an answer to the NSURLSession *session. Very strange...

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function ?
It looks like some dispatch / priority stuff.

Comment: @ΩlostA Use OneSignal for Push it works well. Quite easy to setup too and free.